# Magento Stops Outputting HTML When Encountering Images

Tags: php, html, css, magento

This is for a Magento 1.8.0.0 shop. I purchased a bulk image plugin which required the Magento Connect Manager to install. For the install, I temporarily gave 777 permissions to the entire shop. The plugin installed successfully, however at this point the HTML output just stops when images are encountered.

For example, here are the bottom lines of three separate category pages:

```html
<div class="grid-inner"> <a href="http://www.myshop.com/shop/index.php/accessories/buddy-club-racing-spec-bucket-seat-wide-black.html?___SID=U" title="Buddy Club Racing Spec Bucket Seat (Wide) Black" class="product-image"><img class="pr-img" src="

<div class="grid-inner"> <a href="http://www.myshop.com/shop/index.php/aero/buddy-club-body-kit-rsx-02-04.html?___SID=U" title="Buddy Club Body Kit RSX 02-04" class="product-image"><img class="pr-img" src="

<a href="http://www.myshop.com/shop/index.php/braking/dynalite-big-brake-kit-civic-90-03-240mm-oe-disc-11-rotors-drilled.html?___SID=U" title="DYNALITE BIG BRAKE KIT: CIVIC 90-03 (240mm OE DISC) - 11&quot; ROTORS - DRILLED" class="product-image"><img class="pr-img" src="
```

All of the pages end this way and I can't even browse products.

I have tried re-doing the permissions to a number of different values, removed the plugin, contacted both my template vendor and the plugin vendor, turned on error logging in PHP and switching back to the default theme.

None of these actions have produced a difference. I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting.

h.ubk

Comment: It seems you forgot closing a html element in a template.

Comment: It does, but why don't the images just show blank as in <img src="">. The way it is, there are no close brackets and HTML output immediately stops.

Comment: I would guess that the module has it's own templates and they are failing.  Have you re-compiled? (if compilation is enabled). Have you cleared cache?  Try disabling the module and see if it returns to normal.  Check your server error logs.

Comment: I tried disabling the module, clearing cache and indexes and then I completely removed the module. There has been no difference.

Comment: Ok, very strange but I removed all of the entries for session and cache via the shell and the site is 100% back to normal. I don't have any explanation as to why this didn't work before as I cleared it several times via the web admin console.